# Editing Own Answer Required Peer Review?

Tags: support, status-completed

I just had a strange thing happen. It was revealed that I had a typo in one of [my own answers](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/230/is-there-anyway-to-improve-the-speed-that-list-manager-builds-a-list/1939#1939) regarding a reference number (chopped off a number).  So I went into my answer to fix it, and when I went to save, it gave me all kinds of prompts about the edit not being more than 6 characters, no edit summary message, and when I was done it prompted:

[image]

I thought that odd. I refreshed the page and saw I had a "Review" task... which was to review my own edit... I approved it?

I've not had this issue before, and my rep has been high enough to edit pretty much anything without prompting.

Did something change?

Comment: I'll add to this - @dmytro reported earlier that he'd been awarded the "Can access Site Analytics" priv. Which - well is sort of redundant now that he is a mod - but this would normally only "ping up" at 5K rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you were simply not logged in to the site at the time. It could be that you attempted to edit from an incognito window. The system behavior exactly matches this—your post is now shown to have been edited by Community.

Comment: man. .. not enough coffee today. you're right.. when I clicked on a link, I didn't realize it opened up in a different chrome tab that I wasn't logged into.. Thanks mods. =) You da best!